# Swift: UITableView - swipte to delete - How to have cell content not moving while swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented swipe to delete on UITableView, it works correctly with default behaviour, i.e. content of cell is moving to the left while swiping like on the image. What I want to achive (customize) is to have this delete button appear over the cell content while swiping i.e. text in the cell isn't moved.

I am using this method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

            self.deletionDidStart(of: self.element(for: indexPath)!, at: indexPath)

            // use helper function to delete element at given index path
            let deleted = self.deleteElement(for: indexPath)

            // refresh tableView
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            if let deletedSection = deleted.section {
                self.tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
                self.deletedSection(deletedSection, at: indexPath)
            }
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

            // call deletion event handler
            self.deletedElement(deleted.element!, at: indexPath)
        }

        return [delete]
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `setEditing` method of your `UITableViewCell`,

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    let leadingSpace = 15
    let editingOffset = 80

    if editing == true {
        self.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(leadingSpace + editingOffset)
    } else {
        self.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(leadingSpace);
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

You need to take `IBOutlet` of your `UILabel's` leading Constraint and do it like this way.

This is suggestion only, actual code may be changed depending on your Cell layout.

**UPDATE**

Use below functions as well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Seems to nearly works as I expected. A little problem is instability this method seems to be not always called and sometimes cell content doesn't return to its position. Any idea how to enforce recalculating each time

Comment: @MichałZiobro sometimes cell content doesn't return to its position, is it like so? what is the output of it?

Comment: Yeah I will upvote if I resolve this issue. I will try cause sometimes label leave in the middle of cell after ending editing mode, or is not moved while starting editing mode

Comment: @MichałZiobro update UIView.animate function with duration 0.5

Comment: @MichałZiobro it is working here, can you please verify your code?

Comment: I think the problem is that setEditing is called only first time any cell enters in editing mode. And when swiping another cell setEditing isn't called again. If there will be way to enforce this method call again the solution will be working correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166883/discussion-between-ppl-and-michal-ziobro).

Comment: set editing will be called again if you swipe another cell